# How to create a cluster for TIBCO EMS?

Tags: tibco, tibco-ems

I've created an administration domain on a Windows node, now I need to create a cluster and add that node into that cluster.How do I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no concept of "Cluster" (in a WMQ sense) with EMS, but there are notions of "connected EMS servers" (routes), and bridging of queues (bridges, not unlike WMQ remote queues). There is also the notion of "Multi-instance local HA".

You may want to :

1. Plan your EMS deployment strategy, to proper balance latency, availability, license cost and performance
2. Execute the plan by:

   - Seting up the local HA, with a shared FS if shared state is needed ([here is my article on that](http://www.integist.info/2015/03/19/tibco-ems-8-fault-tolerance-nfs4/))
   - Make use of the "Routes" feature of EMS to link your multiple EMS HA instances together (see page 569 of [the user guide](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/ems/8.2.2/doc/pdf/TIB_ems_8.2_users_guide.pdf))

Note : If you have a limited number of instances but MASSIVE amount of clients, consider multicast OR another product (like FTL or RabbitMQ).

Comment: Got it! by cluster I meant to create a fault tolerant mode! got it now. Thanks ! :)

Comment: Then don't hesitate to vote up and mark as answer ;-) Glad you got what you needed.